# Use unicode field terminator in polybase

Tags: azure, polybase

While creating PolyBase external file format definition for external data stored in Azure blob storage, i am struggling to specify field terminator as a unicode character.
The reason why I want to specify unicode character is because when I am loading data in azure blob using Azure data factory, copy activity doesn't support specifying more than one character as column delimiter unless its a unicode character like **\u0081**

Comment: Can you provide some sample data so we can see your actual delimiter?  You would make life easier for yourself if you used a conventional delimiter like: comma, tab, pipe etc

Comment: Hi wBob,Thanks for your reply. The reason why i cannot use a conventional single character delimiter is because data has a lot of text fields and every combination that i tried has messed up the data in some way i.e. data value will have Pipe character, tab, new line, comma, semi comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql), it suggests custom delimiters are possible but using their hex codes:

```
STRING_DELIMITER = '0x22' -- Double quote hex
STRING_DELIMITER = '0x7E0x7E' -- Two tildas (e.g. ~~)
```

For your example you could try (untested):

```
STRING_DELIMITER = '0x81' -- Control character \u0081
```